# Docker run multiple command prompt

Tags: docker

How do i have multiple command prompts open for my docker ? I have tried launching more command prompts to launch docker but it is wrong.

How do i run my docker with multiple command pormpts

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker ps` to get the container id:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d16a785635b5        python:2.7          "bash"              7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds                            python
```

Then use the container id to `exec` another shell in it:

```
$ docker exec -it d16a785635b5 bash
root@d16a785635b5:/#
```

Repeat as needed.